# Use "custom" sin and cos in glm::rotate

Tags: c++, glm-math, trigonometry, math.h

Is there any way of using my own `sin` and `cos` functions instead of `::std::sin` and `::std::cos` in `glm::rotate(...)` calls?

The only way I can think of, is using macros to replace the `sin` and `cos` symbols inside the `std` namespace, but I really wouldn't like to do that.

Comment: Why? Has the definition of `sin` or `cos` changed recently? Do you really think you can do better than the standard library? On what grounds?

Comment: @EJP: I find these comments annoying - I don't mean to attack you, but every time I ask a very "low-level" optimization question someone always disregards the question and just says "don't do that". I'm experimenting with sprite batching and performance-critical loops and I wanted to measure the performance difference between the usage of a (sintable + cos table), a (sin/cos table) and (std sin cos). No, sin and cos definitions have not changed recently. No, I don't think I can "do better than the standard library". I just wanted to experiment and measure

Comment: Maybe you were genuinely curious about my motives, but your comment gave me the impression of *"look, another dude who stupidly thinks he can do better than the standard library!"*

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Why benchmark with `glm::rotate` ? Why not write your own test framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LD preload will work.

I will explain with a small example.

Assume that this is our main code...

```
int main()
{
   std::cout<< std::sin(1000);
   return 0;
}
```

if I compile and run it, it should print 0.82688

Now I define my own sin

**mysin.hpp**

```
extern "C"
{
    double sin(double);
}
```

**mysin.cpp**

```
#include "mysin.hpp"

double sin(double in)
{
    return in + 10;//do you computation here
}
```

Now compile it as a shared lib

```
g++ -O2 -c -fPIC mysin.cpp -o mysin.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libmysin.so mysin.o -o libmysin.so
```

Assuming original program is compiled as "a.out". Run it with our lib preloaded

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libmysin.so ./a.out
```

Now the result will be "1010".